# Javascript filter returning two individual objects rather than array

Tags: javascript, mongoose, filter

Hi I am using filter to filter through an array and get the length of filtered values returned. However it is returning individual objects rather than an array, so I am unable to use .length on these.

Code I'm using to filter:

```
const pupils = kids.inputs.filter(k => k.attendsSchool);

const number = pupils.length
```

```js
const kids = {
  areaId: "0x2132425",
  inputs: [
    {
      name: "anne",
      gender: "girl",
      age: 6,
      attendsSchool: true,
      _id: "632c78ddae73c67bf67ff2d7",
    },
    {
      name: "bob",
      gender: "boy",
      age: 7,
      attendsSchool: true,
      _id: "632c78ddae73c67bf67ff2d8",
    },
    {
      name: "charlie",
      gender: "boy",
      age: 2,
      attendsSchool: false,
      _id: "632c78ddae73c67bf67ff2d9",
    },
  ]
}
```

What is getting returned to pupils:

> 0: {
>
> "name": "anne",
> "gender": "girl",
> "age": 6,
> "attendsSchool": true,
> "_id": "632c78ddae73c67bf67ff2d7",
> }
>
> 1: { 
> "name": "bob",
> "gender": "boy",
> "age : 7,
> "attendsSchool": true,
> "_id": "632c78ddae73c67bf67ff2d8",
> }

Is there away to get array returned or measure number of items, they are also not in the one object as I can't get length based on object keys

Comment: Weird. Filter does return an array..

Comment: Looks like an array to me

Comment: That is an array

Comment: Are you sure inputs is an array? Given how you formatted it (with json error notably with missing quotes after age) I feel like it is a custom structure/class that provides a filter method

Comment: It is an array. Try to `console.log(Array.isArray(pupils))` and you'll get `true`. If I format your input correctly (see edited question) everything works as expected.

Comment: hmmmm @Mushroomator your edit didn't just change the formatting, you changed the code in meaningful ways which means the question is no longer asking the same thing, and does not demonstrate the problem OP was having. You should revert that edit, do it again *only* changing formatting, then put the corrected code in as an _**Answer**_

Comment: I see your point, but he must have had exactly this structure otherwise his program would not have run as it would be syntactically incorrect, but he's getting a result. If I revert the change, we would need to close the question anyway as it would be syntactically incorrect. In an effort to not close the question but instead help I corrected things in the only possible way (as explained above) to show that everything is working fine. Most likely the output he is getting is just how the browser displays an array.

Comment: given code is giving array.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me as well.
`console.log(number);` returns 2.
`console.log(pupils[0]);` returns the whole object for "anne".

This is using the exact code you have written in your question:
[Codepen snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ul1Vk.png)